# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'EventAggregator' of undefined (Backbone, Marionette, RequireJS)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js, marionette

Creating a new application with Backbone.Marionette, when I run the Express app and load the page I get an error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'EventAggregator' of undefined 
backbone.marionette.js:1504
```

Showing that it's in the actual `marionette` library. I've look at that line:

```
Marionette.EventAggregator = Backbone.Wreqr.EventAggregator;
```

and am thinking that `wreqr` might be an additional library I have to add?

Here's the code that creates the app:

```
require([
    'jquery', 
    'underscore', 
    'backbone', 
    'marionette'
], function( $, _, Backbone, Marionette ){
    MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

    MyApp.addRegions({
        main_region: '#main_region'
    });

    MyApp.addInitializer( function(options) {
        var login_form_view = new LoginFormView();
    });
});
```

and the require config that sets up the library locations:

```
// using RequireJS 1.0.7
    require.config({
        paths: {
            '$': 'libs/jquery-1.8.2-min',
            'underscore': 'libs/underscore-min', // AMD support
            'backbone': 'libs/backbone.min', // AMD support
            'bootstrap' : 'libs/bootstrap.min',
            'marionette' : 'libs/backbone.marionette', 
            'wreqr' : 'libs/backbone.wreqr',
            'templates': '../templates',
            'text': 'libs/require/text', 
            'login': 'views/user/login'
        }
    });
```

Anyone know what could be causing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, wreqr is a dependency to Marionette.

You have specified the path to Wreqr, but you need to load it too. Before you load Marionette.

```
require([
     'jquery', 
     'underscore', 
     'backbone', 
     'wreqr',
     'marionette'
], function( $, _, Backbone, Marionette ){
MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

MyApp.addRegions({
    main_region: '#main_region'
});

MyApp.addInitializer( function(options) {
    var login_form_view = new LoginFormView();
});
```

});

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot and report back. One sec.

Comment: Success! Also had to add EventBinder: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.eventbinder

Comment: FYI: with v1.0.0-beta2, I made it so that the "backbone.marionette.js" file includes Wreqr and EventBinder in it. you can download the "core" marionette.js file without the dependencies if you want, though. http://marionettejs.com#downloads